# Проверка вводимых значений через JS

Tags: javascript

День добрый, подскажите патерн для JS который возвращает true если введено только ОДНО число в диапазоне от 1-8. а не 11 или 88. заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[1-8]$`

или

```
var num=parseInt(inputString),
   result=num<9 && num>0;
```